# How to run javascript in href?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a string of script to run in an href so the link will redirect users depending on an if/else statement.  My code:

```
 <div id="editredirect">
<script>
    if("[@authfield:Authentications_2_Region]" == "[@field:Location_2_Region_ID]"){
    window.location.href = "member-details-edit?CID=[@field:Member_Caspio_ID]&amp;Location_ID=[@field:Member_Location_ID]";
    }
    else if ("[@authfield:Authentications_2_Region]") == "[@field:Location_2_B_Region_ID]"{
    window.location.href = "member-details-edit?CID=[@field:Member_Caspio_ID]&amp;Location_ID=[@field:Member_Location_ID]";
    }
    else {
    window.location.href = "member-details?CID=[@field:Member_Caspio_ID]&amp;Location_ID=[@field:Member_Location_ID]";
    }
</script>
</div>

<style type="text/css">a.ex1:hover {color: #f18c21; text-decoration: underline;}
</style>

<a class="ex1" href="javascript:.initialize(document.getElementById("editredirect"));">Details</a>
```

I've tred do also do a function like this:

```
 <script>
    function editredirect {
    if("[@authfield:Authentications_2_Region]" == "[@field:Location_2_Region_ID]"){
    window.location.href = "member-details-edit?CID=[@field:Member_Caspio_ID]&amp;Location_ID=[@field:Member_Location_ID]";
    }
    else if ("[@authfield:Authentications_2_Region]") == "[@field:Location_2_B_Region_ID]"{
    window.location.href = "member-details-edit?CID=[@field:Member_Caspio_ID]&amp;Location_ID=[@field:Member_Location_ID]";
    }
    else {
    window.location.href = "member-details?CID=[@field:Member_Caspio_ID]&amp;Location_ID=[@field:Member_Location_ID]";
    }
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">a.ex1:hover {color: #f18c21; text-decoration: underline;}
</style>

<a class="ex1" href="javascript:editredirect">Details</a>
```

Neither one will work.  The first string returns a syntax error, the second tells me that "editredirect" is undefined.

Thank you!

***EDIT***

Praveen Kumar's suggestions were the best.  The developer for the database I am using was able to get the application to do it without having to insert any script.  However, they did say that the event listener would have also worked once I had my parameters correct.

Comment: And also some ***** has voted to close as recommendation! LoL. Seriously? Who gave you the close vote right when you couldn't even give the right reason?

Comment: @AlexFenech Your second attempt is already a lot better than the first one. You just forgot the (empty) parameter list behind the function name (both in the definition and in the call). Please keep an eye on any errors reported by the JavaScript console in your web browser,

Comment: Thank you, I will work with the recommendations!  I've only done 2-3 other small snippets of JavaScript and couldn't find a solution anywhere.  I appreciate you guys taking the time to post a response.  The developer for the application I'm using is looking at a better solution than JavaScript that he can build on the back end (it's an authenticated database).  I'll post the final solution once I get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onclick` and add the whole JavaScript logic:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="a = prompt('What\'s your name?'); if (a !== null) alert('Welcome, ' + a); else alert('Bye Bye!'); return false;">Click me?</a>
```

The best way is to use event listener like this:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
  a = prompt('What\'s your name?');
  if (a !== null)
    alert('Welcome, ' + a);
  else
    alert('Bye Bye!');
  return false;
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="#">Click me?</a>
```

This is better than using `href`. If you still want to run it in `href`, you need to create a function and run:

```js
function aha() {
  a = prompt('What\'s your name?');
  if (a !== null)
    alert('Welcome, ' + a);
  else
    alert('Bye Bye!');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:aha();">Click me?</a>
```

> **Note:** In your code, you have used wrong notation. That's a syntax error. JavaScript functions have to be declared in a specific way. Follow that!

Comment: Good question, but thank you for posting your response and help!